# Error parsing XML: duplicate attributes?

Tags: android

I'm having trouble setting the background for my button. I tried setting it to

```
android:background="@drawable/mybutton_background"
```

but that caused an error, saying `"String types not allowed"` referring to `"@drawable/mybutton_background"`. It also caused another error causing me to lose my `R.java` file and giving me the `"R cannot be resolved into a variable error"`. I just gave up on the button and deleted the background, but the error remained after it was deleted. Well, that error is now gone and I now get a message that says Error parsing XML: duplicate attributes for one line of code, but once I delete that line, the error message moves on to another line! It's like Eclipse won't update to realize I deleted that line of code. I checked for updates and cleaned my project countless times, but I'm still getting the same error. Does anyone know what's up with my project?

My error log:

```
activity_main.xml: Paint.setShadowLayer is not supported.
activity_main.xml: Failed to convert @drawable/ into a drawable
activity_main.xml: Failed to convert android:background=" into a drawable
```

activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="android:background=&quot;"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ball01" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton_background"  <----- where I get the error
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Enlighten me!"
        android:textColor="#3f0f7f"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"0        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.crystalball;

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private CrystalBall mCrystalBall = new CrystalBall();
    private TextView mAnswerLabel;
    private Button mGetAnswerButton;
    private ImageView mCrystallBallImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAnswerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mGetAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mCrystallBallImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        mGetAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String answer = mCrystalBall.getAnAnswer();

                mAnswerLabel.setText(answer);

                animateCrystalBall();
                animateAnswer();
            }
        });
    }

    public void animateCrystalBall() {
        mCrystallBallImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_animation);
        AnimationDrawable ballAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mCrystallBallImage.getDrawable();
        if (ballAnimation.isRunning()) {
            ballAnimation.stop();
        }
        ballAnimation.start();
    }

    private void animateAnswer() {
        AlphaAnimation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1500);
        fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        mAnswerLabel.setAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thanks for anything you can contribute!

Comment: Check out this line in your RelativeLayout `android:background="android:background=&quot;"` this is also **WRONG**

Comment: Thanks! I got an error message there too. And that might be what's screwing it up. What should it be?

Comment: Nothing at all, if you don't want a global layout background. Or, `android:background="@drawable/your_drawable_here"` if you want it.

Answer (score 49):

In my case this error was due to duplicate xmlns attributes inside layout. If you have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="person"
            type="com.abc.PersonEntity" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
...
```

Remove the xmlns attribute from the second layout:

```
    <LinearLayout 
...
```

Comment: This also happens when you have extra attributes like `layout_width` or `layout_height` on the `<layout ` view

Answer (score 4):

From the parent `RelativeLayout` XMl `android:background="android:background=&quot;"` or update it with a drawable or with color as `android:background="#FFFF00"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="android:background=&quot;" <---remove this or update with correct drawable
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
```

In this below `Button` XML, you have added `android:background` attribute 2 times...Which causing the problem.

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/"  <-----first time
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton_background"  <-----second time
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:text="Enlighten me!"
    android:textColor="#3f0f7f"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Now, remove the first one...your problem will be solved.

Comment: Sorry, I was playing with it and tried to add a background twice then take it away to see if that would remove the error. I deleted the first background, and the message remains at android:background=:drawable/my_button" after I cleaned the project.

Comment: After I deleted the background. The error moved to android:focusableInTouchMode="true" beneath it.

Answer (score 1):

You have the attribute background repeated

```
        android:background="@drawable/"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton_background"  <----- where I get the error
```

Answer (score 1):

`android:background="android:background=&quot;"` <--quot; `remove code here`

Look at this line in your parent relative layout. Just remove the background from here. Because of this line it causes "String types not allowed".

And second problem in below Button XML, you have added `android:background` 2 times...Which causing `"Error parsing XML: duplicate attributes for one line of code".` So just remove one background.

enter code here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"`enter code here`
    android:background="android:background=&quot;" <--Remove this line
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ball01" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/"<-- Remove this line
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton_background"  <----- where I get the error
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Enlighten me!"
        android:textColor="#3f0f7f"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"0 <--remove this 0 from here.       
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case error was due to 2 id's
    android:id="@+id/layout" ( id)
    and 
    android:id="@+id/parent" (Linear layout id)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:background="@color/plain_background">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` was missing in one of the manifests. In integrated debug manifest file this attribute is shown twice. Adding this attribute to each amnifest (even an empty one) solved the problem.